# javascript library/framework for html5 mobile apps to deal with UI orientation

Tags: library, javascript, html, framework

My requirement goes something like follows:

Say I am building an angular js app for, say, a samsung galaxy tab p3100.

When you hold the tablet vertically with the short-side facing upwards you want one simple view, say, a login form.

When you hold the tablet with the long-side up, the screen rotates. In this orientation, there is more real estate, hence, the login form occupies the first 4 columns and the rest 8 columns will host some other content - advertisements, etc. (Bootstrap vocabulary - dividing the screen to a 12 column layout).

[image]

Content should be dynamic as per device orientation.

What is a good library or framework that has an easy way to write such apps?

Comment: I would suggest making title slightly more verbose (mention about UI or at least orientation)

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement I recommend [jquery](http://jquerymobile.com/) mobile framework becase it allows you to design a single highly-branded responsive web site or application that will work on all popular smartphones.

Comment: And if you want to use more than just 1 library, I suggest you have a look at http://www.requirejs.org/ It will help in modularizing your code and specifying the dependencies of each script.

Comment: Is there a declarative way of saying what to show in portrait and landscape orientations?